# Could not load file or assembly 'Ajax' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, ajax

I am working a c# web service with Visual Studio 2005, the following error will occur occasionally when I debug my web service. Every time I run into this problem, I restart my computer then it doesn't occur again.

It's so strange!!! How to resolve this problem?

> Could not load file or assembly 'Ajax' or one of its dependencies.
>   Access is denied.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Ajax' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't see the FusionLog and I read Access Denied I guess that file permissions for the "Ajax" Assemlby are wrong. Doublecheck them.